# C++ adjust std::string to have 16 bytes size maximum

Tags: c++, stdstring

I'm porting MSVC6 application to MSVC9 as the old size of `std::string` is 16 bytes (this one is from a 1998 package) and the new one is 32 bytes which completely makes my application impossible to work since it was built with 4 byte alignment option and uses some size checking/comparing compatible with the old size.

I need to reimplement this MSVC6 `std::string`... or just use some smaller string implementation.

Is it possible to make current size of `std::string` smaller e.g. by using some different allocator or something? I need to make it working.

```
//MSVC6 Works
//MSVC9 Not...
class myappstring : std::string
{

};
```

Comment: I'd throw that old code away...

Comment: You'll have to use some kind of replacement if the size of std::string really is a problem. But more ideally, I think a program should never be written in a way that it matters.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish In fact, not even a serializer should :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default allocator isn't stored in `std::string` instances so it shouldn't have any effect on the size of `std::string`s. You'll simply have to switch to another string implementation, perhaps one you've written to meet your requirements.